# Text disorders when I lower the page size

Tags: html, css

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNuH2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qYqi.png)

Hello, I'm new at web development and I wanted to know why my texts overlap when I reduce the page size. I tried with flex too but idk the issue

```html
 <div class="container-fluid contenedorExp">

      
      <div class="lineaSecundaria"></div>

      <div class="row fila d-flex">

        <div class="col-md-1 align-self-top columnaImg">
          <img src="./img/mcdonalds.png" class="foto">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 d-flex flex-column">
          <p class="empleo">McDonald's</p>
          <p class="descripcion">Empleado</p>
          <p class="descripcion">dic - 2015 a mar - 2016</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="lineaSecundaria"></div>

      
      <div class="row fila d-flex">

        <div class="col-sm-1 align-self-top columnaImg">
          <img src="./img/rossi.png" class="foto">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p class="empleo">Rossi</p>
          <p class="descripcion">Cadete</p>
          <p class="descripcion">dic - 2018 a mar - 2020</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please include your CSS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.